# Disable vertical scroll bar on div overflow: auto

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

Is it possible to allow only a horizontal scroll bar when using overflow:auto (or scroll)?

Comment: Note that `margin-bottom` with a negative value will mess with `overflow-y: hidden` etc.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

These two CSS properties can be used to hide the scrollbars:

```
overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical
overflow-x: hidden; // hide horizontal
```

Comment: @Coulton What about safari and chrome?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) it works in Safari and I know it works in Chrome.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can still scroll in the div using `tab`, provided there are links or input elements in the hidden overflow

Answer (score 41):

You should use only

**`overflow-y:hidden;`**  - Use this for hiding the Vertical scroll

**`overflow-x:auto;`**  - Use this to show Horizontal scroll

Luke has mentioned as both hidden. so I have given this separately.

Answer (score 21):

overflow: auto; 
overflow-y: hidden;

For IE8:
-ms-overflow-y: hidden;

Or Else :

**To hide X**:

```
<div style="height:150x; width:450px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y: scroll; padding-bottom:10px;"></div>
```

**To hide Y**:

```
<div style="height:150px; width:450px; overflow-x:scroll ; overflow-y: hidden; padding-bottom:10px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to accomplish the same in Gecko (NS6+, Mozilla, etc) and IE4+ simultaneously, I believe this should do the trick:V

```
body {
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This will be applied to entire body tag, please update it to your relevant css and apply this properties.

Answer (score 3):

How about a shorthand notation?

```
{overflow: auto hidden;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following:

```
body{
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This rules are compatible whit all browser:

```
body {overflow: hidden; }
body::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important; }
body { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
body { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to disable the scrollbar, but still able to scroll the content of inner DIV, 
use below code in css,

```
.divHideScroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0 !important
}
.divHideScroll {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}
.divHideScroll {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

divHideScroll is the class name of the target div.

It will work in all major browser (Chrome, Safari, Mozilla, Opera, and IE)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
html, body
    {
      -ms-content-zooming:none;  
      touch-action: none;
      content-zooming: none;
      overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: none; // hide vertical
    overflow-x: none; 
    }
```