# Completely disable ANY kind of vertical scroll in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, overflow, vertical-scroll

I need to disable ANY kind of vertical scrolling within an overflown DIV (I would still be able to scroll it horizontally).

**overflow:hidden** with CSS won't work since you can still scroll with the mouse wheel click / smartphone touch scroll. The only thing this does is hide the scroll bar, not disable it.

Is there any way to do this with Javascript or jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646538/disable-vertical-scroll-bar-on-div-overflow-auto

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily ... maybe can help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reducing the height of the div so there is no where to scroll.

You could put the screen height into a variable (or slightly less) and then make the div the same height therefore cutting off any content with the overflow hidden.